# Apply function over Spark dataset

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Assume I have this in pyspark:

```
data = [{"age":1,"count":10},{"age":2,"count":20},{"age":3,"count":30}]

rdd = sc.parallelize( data )
```

I want to make "count" + 10 if "age" is larger than 2.
Like this :

```
data = [{"age":1,"count":10},{"age":2,"count":20},{"age":3,"count":40}]
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be better solution. This one works for me.

```
def add_count(x):
    x['count']+=10
    return x
    
new_data = list(map(lambda x: x if x['age']<=2 else add_count(x), data))
```

Comment: This isn't using Spark, though

Answer (score 4):

You can convert to `Dataframe` and it's much easier

```
df = rdd.toDF()

df.withColumn("count", when(df['age'] > 2, df['count'] + 10).otherwise(df['count'])).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+
|age|count|
+---+-----+
|1  |10   |
|2  |30   |
|3  |40   |
+---+-----+
```